# Healthcare in Portugal for Germans

Tags: health-insurance, health-care, german-citizens, portugal

[Question was previously on Travel]
I live in Germany, and applied for a job (in science) in Lisbon. My husband (German too), a programmer, would come too. He's insured by TK (the main state health insurance in Germany) and had chemo for a chronic Lymphoma about two years ago. Right now, he needs regular checkups and we just need to know that he would get good treatment, should he need it again.

So I have three related questions:

How is health insurance in Lisbon? Could we expect that he gets quality treatment and all the necessary checkups (blood tests, flow cytometry, ultrasounds)?

Would it suffice to get the Portuguese state health insurance, or would we need a private one? I know of some excellent cancer clinics (the Champalimaud centre) but I think it's only accessible through private insurance. I assume that private insurances would be too expensive with a pre-existing condition.

Is there a way that he can stay in the German system (we would be willing to pay for the time we're away)